# Show data from controller into jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I saw a lot of examples how to show data, which I defined and put into java controller, but I can't do it. The code is here.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping({"/","/test"})
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap model) {
        String mes = "Here I am";
        model.addAttribute("message",mes);
        return "new";
    }
}
```

new.jsp file

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

When I'm starting the jsp page show only like this ${message}

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.sbt"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: You've to hit the controller path instead of JSP path directly.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: I guess @RohitJain means to access not /new.jsp, but /test

Comment: It isn't a problem. I can access to my page. I don't have a message which I putted into controller

Comment: @jenius Well, the message is added to ModelAttribute by controller only. You've to access the controller, which will redirect you to JSP page. Although you can access your JSP page, you should not do that.

Comment: And what should I do? Could you advice something?

Comment: @Rohit Jain and what?

Comment: @jenius what the URL you are using to access the controller ?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: post your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml . Are you using an InternalResourceViewResolver?

Comment: mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml posted

Answer (score 1):

Do not directly hit the jsp page means do not put direct jsp name in url instead put **/test**(requestMapping url) that is call your controller and then controller will send jsp with **model**(data) to client request

Comment: I don't inderstand you. Write what is wrong in code

Comment: how are you calling this program from your browser copy paste here the url you are hitting in your browser.